# Does anyone know of a .NET enum of Comparison Operators in System or System.Core?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, system, comparison-operators

Is there an enum in System or System.Core that has all the ComparisonOperators?

I just wrote the following enum, but it seems like a common enough thing that one might already exist.

```
public enum ComparisonPredicate
{
    Equal,
    Unequal,
    LessThan,
    LessThanOrEqualTo,
    GreaterThan,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo
}
```

I found one in System.Web.UI, but it would be more than silly to introduce a dependency for that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationcompareoperator(v=VS.100).aspx

Also, I already looked at `ExpressionType`, but I don't want something with that broad of a scope

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I am also wondering what you would need this for.  The enum would have an integer value.  I don't see how this could be useful.

Comment: @Dykam, @Ramhound, My immediate use case is an extension method that converts a `Comparison<T>` to a `Predicate<T>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFIK such a thing does not exist.  You are probably better off using your own, for now.

Answer (score 8):

A bit late, but .Net 3.5 introduced the `ExpressionType` enumeration in `System.Linq.Expressions`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179(v=vs.110).aspx for more details.

Comment: see the OP "Also, I already looked at ExpressionType, but I don't want something with that broad of a scope"

Answer (score -4):

This is the top result on Google however since I am writing this in 2018, and in the area of .Net 4.5+, the correct answer is:

```
Enum.Equals();
```

See [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You are providing the method to compare two enums. That is not what's asked: the original question asks for an enumerate containing comparison operators.